# Sections of a vector bundle are locally vector valued

Tags: vector-bundles

Can someone explain to me what it means to say that "the sections of a vector bundle are locally vector valued". Does it mean that for every point $x\in X$ , the base space, there is a neighbourhood $U$ containing $x$ such that under the local trivialisation of $U$, i.e. when the section $s\restriction_U$ is conjugated by the isomorphism trivialising $p^{-1}(U)$,  it takes the same vector value for all $x\in U$.

Comment: It means that if $\pi:E\to B$ is a fiber bundle then a section $s:U\subset B \to E$ send any point $x\in U$ to a vector $s(x)\in E_x$ where $E_x$ is the fiber over $x.$ (Note that it has not meaning to say $s(x)=s(y)$ for $x\ne y$ because $E_x$ and $E_y$ are different vector spaces.) This is always possible locally but not necessarily globally.

Comment: What I meant to ask is that under the isomorphism, $\varphi:p^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times V$ will the images of $s(x)$ and $s(y)$ be the same vector in V?

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider $p:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}, p(x,y)=x.$ Then $s(x)=(x,2x)$ is a section. But $s(0)\ne s(1).$ (Note that $\varphi$ is just the identity in this case.)

Comment: So there may be many trivialisations of a particular open set in $X$, right.

Comment: Do you mean many sections?

Comment: What I am saying is that there may be many maps like $\varphi$, which trivialize $p^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: But I understood your point, my question has a negative answer. Even in the example which you gave, which is a product budle itself, the section takes different vector values for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thanks.